# Apache 404 Not Found

Tags: windows-7, networking, firefox, apache-http-server

I am running an apache server on my win 7 pc mostly for the purpose of serving data I control to various scripts I write for my friends.

Right now I have a resource hosted on it called "latestmc.txt". The script that's using it works fine on all computers, other computers (on the local network anyway, I haven't tried outside) can access the file through a web browser using both the external and LAN address, and firefox on my computer can access it using localhost or the LAN address. The only problem is, firefox on my computer can not access the file using the external address. Trying this yields a 404 Not Found error. Even IE has no problem using ether address.

It seems to be just firefox and just the external address on just this computer that cause the problem. Firefox can even access the apache index.html using the external address but not the latestmc.txt (they are in the same dir). Any ideas guys?

EDIT: Really guys, I'm open to any theories :)

EDIT: Figured it out. Look in the comments of Simons answer for more info

Answer (score 0):

I would guess/bet this has to do with file permissions or possibly Firefox is prepending "http" or "www".

I know Linux handles symbolic link properly while You can't have symbolic links in your web root on windows. Not sure if you're using symbolic links or not.

Finally, I would change the extensions to htm and see if it's visible. Even change it to index.htm to try that. Finally, create an empty folder on the server and see if Firefox can access directories.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I believe it was a problem with firefox having cached a 404 page and bringing that back up when it heared that the file had not been modify. As soon as I started playing with the file's extension, it updated and started working again :)